# Catching inner JSF exceptions and handling them on my own

Tags: jsf

I am using JSF 1.2.

I would like to be able to catch the JSF internal exceptions to produce a better looking error page and maybe try to re-load the session (Using backing bean data)

How Can I do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't mention what version of JSF you are using, but in JSF 2.0 all JSF exceptions thrown by the framework are being published as events and handled by a global ExceptionHandler. You can replace this with your own implementation in faces-config.xml:

```
<exception-handlerfactory>
   com.foo.myExceptionHandler
</exception-handlerfactory>
```

See this answer for some additional details: [Differences between action and actionListener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3909267/differences-between-action-and-actionlistener/4483339#4483339)

Comment: Your right. I'm using 1.2 but I will definitely check on how to upgrade to 2.0 without causing too much trouble.